# How to keep a timing dependent C process from context switching

Tags: kernel, process, raspberry-pi, embedded

We have a process that is responsible for polling hardware at time-dependent intervals. We would like to dedicate a CPU core to this process. E.g. we want this process to remain runnable at all times.

Our first attempt to solve this problem was the following:

```
# Set process to highest priority
nice -n -20 cmd

# Set thread affinity in C for our hardware sampling thread
pthread_setaffinity_np(...)
```

Both steps above work as expected. Our thread stays on `core3` where we set it, and `nice` is `-20` in top.

When re run `ftrace` as [per this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774217/cannot-avoid-context-switches-on-a-process-launched-alone-on-a-cpu) and [this issue](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=113853), we commonly see the following:

```
> cat trace | grep " 3)" | grep " => "
 3)  rhd_loc-2735  =>    <idle>-0   
 3)    <idle>-0    =>  rhd_loc-2735 
 3)  rhd_loc-2735  =>    <idle>-0   
 3)    <idle>-0    =>  rhd_loc-2735 
 3)  rhd_loc-2735  =>    <idle>-0   
 3)    <idle>-0    =>  rhd_loc-2735
```

`rhd_loc-2735` is our process.

In addition to what is shown above we see many cases where `kworker-2703` switches in, and sometimes other lower priority processes swap into the core.

We believe the reason for the context switches is that our process communicates with `SPI` (Serial Peripheral Interface) which waits on `IRQs`, and also `SPI` runs at a clock rate an order of magnitude slower than the CPU core. Therefore our process spends much of its time waiting on SPI/IRQs, e.g. it's not in a `Runnable` state. Regardless of the priority or affinity, the kernel is free to assign other processes to the core.

This causes our hardware sampling rate to be more variable and lower than it could be because our CPU core is not always immediately ready to process the next value from `SPI` and then submit a new sampling request.

**Question:**

> Can we either 1) force all other processes to stay out of the core so that our process can immediately respond to interrupt requests, or 2) keep our main thread Runnable so that it is always available to process the next request?

Comment: The generic linux kernel is not real time.  You are asking for real time features.  You should try a real time kernel and research how to take advantage of its features.

Comment: I would rather suggest to hide one core from the linux system and let some bare metal RTOS run on that core for the real-time tasks.

Comment: I haven't looked into it, but it is possible the real time kernel supports that.

Comment: So far we've applies `PREEMPT_RT` patch. Jitter in sampling rate improved substantially, but we didn't eliminate jitter entirely. We're currently trying to pin down whether SPI bus speed variability (a common concern on embedded PI forums) and/or process context switches are responsible for the remaining jitter. @Philippos if you could elaborate on your suggestion that would make a great answer. I wasn't aware that it's possible to run linux on 3 cores and a RTOS on 1 core. Would love to have some pointers to where to learn about that.

Comment: I haven't done it myself, so I don't feel able to make a good elaboration. During the last years, more SoCs came to market with come Cortex-A performance cores and a Cortex-M real time core, which is nowadays the preferred platform for what you are looking for. I suggest to have a look at https://github.com/siemens/jailhouse, which seems to be the most active approach.